# Infinite Scroll with Sidebar Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading results via Ajax. I'm paging the results using infinite scrolling. 
I have a nifty little sidebar that follows the page as new contents load.

The problem I'm facing now is that the nifty sidebar has the letters A-Z in it. When a user clicks on one of those letters I need to unbind the scroll event -> create placeholder's from the last section loaded thru the next section requested (A-Z) -> load the requested section and than proceed re-bind the $(window).scroll(). It actually works (or is supposed to work) closely to Facebook's Timeline.

What I cannot for the life of me figure out is how to unbind the scroll event when you click on the sidebar. I've ripped out a the fixed sidebar code and data retrieval because it doesn't serve a purpose here.

A bit of code...

```
// i use this array to figure out which section of data i need next
var letters = new Array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

// get the default set of data to display BEFORE scroll
// -> some code...

// remove letter from array
letters.splice(0, 1);

// scroll
$(window).scroll(function(event){
var doc_height          = parseInt($(document).height()),
    window_height       = parseInt($(window).height()),
    scroll_at_height    = parseFloat(doc_height - parseFloat(doc_height / 10) - window_height),
    scroll_y            = $(window).scrollTop();

// check if the scroll height is met and pull next recordset
if (scroll_y >= scroll_at_height) {

    // as long as there are still more sections to go [var letters]
    if (letters.length > 0) {

        // get next set
        // -> some code to get the next set of data...

        // remove letter from [letters] array
        letters.splice(0, 1);
    }
}
});

// sidebar nav
$('.letter-picker a').bind('click', function() {
// nothing here works anywho...

return false;
});
```

Comment: Wow. Umm, so I honestly tried $(window).unbind(scroll); and it wasn't working before and now it is. -1 for developing on a Windows box.